# Wordpress REST API not displaying

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to setup a headless Wordpress backend using wordpress version 4.9.7
However trying to test the GET request results in an error 404.
This happens only in the above version, tested it on other sites with versions 4.9.1 and 4.9.5 and it is working just fine.

Any work around on this?

Comment: Have you disabled it? Did you set pretty permalinks or if not [use the alternative routes](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints)?

Comment: Difficult to help you with this unless you include the code that you are using. Please include this so we can advise.

Comment: I have not used any code yet, just installed without any modifications to the wordpress files

Update
it had to do with the permalink, set it to post name and its now working, Thank you @kero